# Effective way to remove unused fields of JRXML report template

Tags: jasper-reports, field, ireport, unused-variables

Recently I had to remove many groups from my report. It caused that in my report template left a lot of unnecessary fields and variables (the removed groups these fields and variables).

Does anybody know quick way to remove unused fields and variables? I'm using iReport, but unfortunately I haven't found such functionality. I emphasize there's a lot of unused fields and doing it manually is not an option.

I consider writing own program, which would do it automatically, but before I would make sure that's needed.

Thanks in advance for your help.